# What does the WQL Select * from SQLService return 0 rows in WBEMTest mean?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, security

So, I've been trying to solve the blue icon question mark on my sql server  in SQL Server Management Studio by following the answer in the following link:

[Blue icon with question mark - what does it mean?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176666/blue-icon-with-question-mark-what-does-it-mean/176674)

after executing the above recommended answer I was still unable to resolve this question mark icon issue and to prove that it was related to the WMI I followed these steps:

1. In windows Start > Run > WBEMTest
2. Type the following under namespace `\\NameOfMyServerOrMachine\root\Microsoft\SQLServer\ComputerManagement13`
3. Click on "Query..."
4. Enter Query `Select * from SQLService` and Apply
5. I get 0 rows

**What does this mean? what else am I missing?**

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Added my windows user to the `Distributed COM Users` and `Performance Monitor Users`
2. in my sql server machine, I opened the WMI Control and gave permissions to group `Performance Monitor Users` so that they could have `Enable Account` and `Remote Enable` access to the namespace and subnamespaces on : `\\NameOfMyServerOrMachine\root\Microsoft\SQLServer\ComputerManagement13`
3. Verified that the WMI service is running in the sql server machine
4. TCP Port 135 is enabled and open in the guest machines
5. `Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)` and `Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)`  Inbound rule is enabled in the guest machines firewall.

Any thoughts?