# how to Enable these Windows Firewall rules using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, connectivity, powershell, windows-server

I have a few servers where I see a blue question mark on the sql server service, as per the picture below.

[image]

[This is the solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/197386/22336):

> Enabling these Windows Firewall rules did the trick for me
>
> Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)
>
> Windows Management
> Instrumentation (DCOM-In)

Is there a way I could achieve this via powershell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use the [`Enable-NetFirewallRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/enable-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps) cmdlet:

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule -Name "WMI-WINMGMT-In-TCP", "WMI-RPCSS-In-TCP"
```

In order to find the relevant rule names (in order to enable it), you can search existing firewall rules by name by using the `Get-NetFirewallRule` cmdlet, for example:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name "*WMI*"
```

This uses wildcards to final all the rules that contain "WMI" as an example.

Comment: Small note, you can shortcut the command by providing both names together. So `Enable-NetFirewallRule -Name 'WMI-WINMGMT-In-TCP','WMI-RPCSS-In-TCP'` would have the same effect.

Comment: @ShawnMelton Thanks!  I don't use PowerShell super often these days, and always forget exactly what syntax to use for passing lists like that.  So I just default to multiple commands =)  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, it works either way. Some prefer to use multiple for readability when they are just glancing....as long as it gets the job done.