# How to copy all firewall rules and apply them on a new server?

Tags: sql-server, security, installation, connectivity, powershell

I often [install new SQL Server Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-installation-wizard-setup?view=sql-server-2017). Be them production, test or development.

There is one thing I still have not automated and it is time consuming: [the firewall settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc740047(v=ws.10)).

I know how to [Configure Windows Firewall to Work with SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1929/configure-windows-firewall-to-work-with-sql-server/) but I want to automate it.

I want to be able to copy all settings from a firewall in an already existing server `my_good_server_already_running` and apply all those settings to `my_new_server`.

How can I get this done?

well, [how to Enable these Windows Firewall rules using powershell?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225944/how-to-enable-these-windows-firewall-rules-using-powershell) gives me an idea.

From [Use PowerShell to List Firewall Rules](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/08/powertip-use-powershell-to-list-firewall-rules/) I got the following script that allows me to list all the firewall rules that I am interested in:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.Enabled –eq ‘True’ –and $_.Direction –eq ‘Inbound’ }

Get-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.Enabled –eq ‘True’ –and $_.Direction –eq ‘Outbound’ }
```

How do I get these rules and make them a script to apply on `my_new_server`?

I tried [Managing the Windows Firewall with PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/managing-the-windows-firewall-with-powershell/) but it doesn't say how to make the applying script out of the list either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am delighted to say that I have used the link provided by [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin) in the comments,
and it worked fine, although the order is not the same, and the original server was involved in clustering and the new one is not.....

I recommend this script, for those who need to deal with database server installations, and consequently firewalls.

[Powershell scripts to export and import firewall rules](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-to-export-and-23287694)

This is a partial picture of the firewall on the original server:
[image]

This is a partial picture of the firewall on the new server:
[image]