# sql server connectivity broke down to server after its IP address has moved to a subnet. How to restore its connectivity?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, connectivity, tcpip

I a server called `Vermont` on a [different domain](https://www.visittheusa.com/state/vermont), with a trust relationship.

I can ping the server there.
[image]

But when I try to connect to it, from my SSMS I get the following error:

[image]

I used to connect to that server, and I have replication set up, and the `Vermont Server` is one of the publishers.

I called the people there and I have been told that they have moved the IP address of `Vermont` to a subnet.

Despite [allowing sql server to connect through the firewall](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/227481/22336), 
what else I need to put in place in order for me to connect to my local machine to the `Vermont server`?

I understand that the `Vermont` server needs to `allow remote connection`

[image]

I also understand that the sql protocols like tcp/ip and the ports must be open and set. 1433 for tcp/ip and let's say 1434 for named pipes.

I have domain accounts that would have permissions to connect to `Vermont` or any sql server server in either of our domains.

what else could be missing that I cannot connect to the `Vermont` server?

Comment: Is there a firewall between you and the server?  If yes, that would be the first thing to check.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the server with the IP address or the FQDN?