# I am trying to connect My R studio to SQL Database on the Remote Desktop

Tags: sql-server, security, connectivity, logins

The SQL Server on the remote desktop is configured to have neither login nor password, it is configured to use Windows Authentication.

#### Code

I am using the following code to connect:

```
library(DBI)
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver=SQl Server;server=FAC-270938-ENG2;Database=HRMS')
```

#### Error Generated

Warning messages:

1:

```
    In odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQl Server;server=FAC-270938-ENG2;Database=HRMS") :
      [RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code 18456, 
message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

Login failed for user 'HMINDIA\274074'
```

2:

```
In odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQl Server;server=FAC-270938-ENG2;Database=HRMS")
   ODBC connection failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you failed to connect to your SQL Server, the issue could be:

1. Network issue. SQL Server configuration issue.
2. Firewall issue.
3. Client driver issue.
4. Application configuration issue.
5. Authentication
       and logon issue.

Check [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/) for more details.

In your error message it is just a login failure:

> Login failed for user 'HMINDIA\274074'

you need to create a login.
there are windows logins and sql logins:

for example (windows login - attached to the active directory):

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [my_domain\my_login] 
FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO

--grant the access and permissions accordingly
--in this case it is a sysadmin
--ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [my_domain\my_login]
GO
```

example of creating a sql login:

```
USE [master]
GO


CREATE LOGIN [my_ETL_login] WITH PASSWORD=N'Hare_Krishna108', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

-- grant access to this login
-- this login will be able to access and read database CAMemeMail:

    USE [CAMemeMail]
    GO
    CREATE USER [my_ETL_login] FOR LOGIN [my_ETL_login]
    GO
    USE [CAMemeMail]
    GO
    ALTER USER [my_ETL_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
    GO
    USE [CAMemeMail]
    GO
    ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [my_ETL_login]
    GO
```

And don't forget the [firewall](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/227481/22336)